# How to write Jest Unit Test for function with fs.readFileSync

Tags: node.js, jestjs

So I have this function in AuthService.js

[AuthService.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9StXN.png)

and I wrote these tests to test this function

[AuthService.test.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFRW8.png)

The test runs successfully for the first 2 tests, but the 3rd one fails and shows this error.

Unable to login, please check your crediential!

```
  60 |       };
  61 |     }
> 62 |     throw new Error('Unable to login, please check your crediential!');
     |           ^
  63 |   }
  64 |
  65 |   async verifyStaff(payload) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mock `fs.readFileSync` so that in your test you can tell the mock to return the expected result (you probably don't want your unit test to actually talk to your file system).

You can do this with the jest `mock` function:

```
jest.mock('fs');
```

Then the imported functions like `readFileSync` will be a `jest.Mock` that supports things like `readFileSync.mockReturnValue("a test file");`:

https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions